# What are these names represent? after doing the git config --list

Tags: git-config

I am trying to see my author's details, But including the author's details, I got this.
can anyone explain ..what exactly it is?

`core.repositoryformatversion=0 core.filemode=true core.bare=false core.logallrefupdates=true`

Comment: hi @Gurudath! was the answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

- `core.repositoryformatversion`: can be either 0 or 1 (default 0), it specifies whether your repo supports extensions to git's standard functionalities ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/repository-version))
- `core.filemode`: boolean, when false, git will not consider changes to file permissions as file changes (i.e., file permission changes won't be tracked) ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corefileMode))
- `core.bare`: a bare repo is a repo without working tree (i.e., without `.git` directory). For the implications, check out the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corebare)
- `core. logAllRefUpdates` : to enable or disable the reflog, i.e., the logical log that tracks updates to the tip of branches ([docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corelogAllRefUpdates))